# How to create an annuity timeline on LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, moderntimeline

I was wondering, how can I create a timeline exactly like this one:

[image]

on LaTeX?

I am a Finance student, and write all of my notes using LaTeX. These timelines, are giving me a headache. Since we use a lot of different timelines because of annuities. I want to learn how to create one basic timeline, so that I can then change anything I want. But basically, I want something like this, with the arrows and everything.

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) *always* and help us.

Answer (score 6):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- node[below=1mm,pos=0.6,scale=2] {$\cdots$} (10,0)node[right=4mm]{(periods)};
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/2,3/3,9/$n-1$,10/$n$}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- (\x,2mm)node[above]{$\$ 1$};
    }
    \draw[-latex] (0,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$A_{ni}$};
    \draw[-latex] (10,-7mm) -- +(0,-10mm)node[below]{$S_{ni}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using the *chronosys* or the *chronology* package. Have a look at the packages and documentation at www.ctan.org

Comment: I think that you may add a comment rather that put this in an answer