# how to create a term-life annuity timeline on LaTex

Tags: symbols, amsmath, tikz-styles, tikz-cd, timeline

how to create a term-life annuity timeline like this

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241153/197451

Comment: @MARRYHERLINGGA  -- welcome to the site -- please have a look a the answer below if it suits the requirement -- I have not completed the full labeling on the left but should give u an idea where to start

Comment: Hello! I think you asked the same exact question on Dec 1 at 17:28 and it was already closed as a duplicate. Why are you asking it again?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) --  (7,0);
  \draw[line width=1pt] (8,0) --  (10,0);
  \draw[loosely dotted, thick]  (7,0) --(8,0);
  \foreach \y/\x/\q/\w in {0/0/1/1,1/2/v/px,2/4/v2/2px,3/6/v3/3px,$n-1$/8/vn-1/n-1px,$n$/10//}{
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-5mm) node[below](\x){$1$} -- (\x,5mm)node[above](){\y};
    \node[below=1em of \x](\q){\q};
    \node[below=4em of \x](\w){\w};
}
    \node at (-2,5mm)[] (a) {};
    \node [above=0pt of a] () {Time};
    \node [left=3em of 0] () {Amount};
    \node [left=3em of 1] () {Probability};
    \node [left=3em of 0] () {Amount};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Time Line Diagram} \label{fig:M1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```